# Regression on Linear Model?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, machine-learning

I have 50 or so training examples involving a set of 200 or so real numbers (x1,x2,...,x200) (normalized to a 0 mean and std dev 1), and a single output real (y) in the range 0.0..1.0.  I want to fit a linear model as follows:

```
y = w0 + w1 * x1 + w2 * x2 + ... + w200 * x200
```

So I need to calculate (w0,w1,w2,...,w200) based on the training examples.  By what formula or algorithm should I calculate these weights?

Comment: Because your number of free variables (200) is more than the number of training samples (50), the problem is under-determined.  There are an infinite number of exact solutions.

Comment: @Tpofofn the post is tagged `(machine-learning)` and `(regression)` in such setting it is *always* the case that the number of training samples $<$ the number of variables (aka features). Methods such as least squares can find *a* solution which minimizes, say, sum of squared error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole area of [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) studying all different aglorithms to do that. You probably can't  visualize your data because it lives in $\mathbb{R}^{200}.$

I guess you should try least squares. Let $X : \mathbb{R}^{50\times 201}$ be your feature matrix augmented with column of $1$'s (to account for $w_0$). $X$ has $50$ rows; one for each training example. Each row looks like: $$(1, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{200}).$$ Let $y : \mathbb{R}^{50\times 1}$ be your output vector.

The [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) will solve for $w$ in $Xw = y,$ where $w : \mathbb{R}^{201\times 1}$ are the weights you're looking for.

The naive solution is solving the following linear system for $w$:
$$ X^{T}Xw = X^{T}y, $$
but better numerical methods exist.